# React list is always empty during function call - causing duplicate values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm having trouble preventing duplicate values because my item list is empty every time the function is called. But I know that list contains items.

The function is called AddToCart, and I'm passing it down to a child component called inventoryModal. I want this function to check the existing state array of cart items to make sure the requested productID hasn't already been added when it's selected from the inventory modal.

[image]

Everything works the way I'm expecting when I add items. BUT, I'm unable to prevent duplicates from being added to the cart. Every time the AddToCart function is called, the cartItems array saved in the state is empty so the item is allowed to be added as a duplicate. I know  the cartItems array isn't empty because I have cartItems appearing on my screen as I click the buttons in the menu.

Below is the function I'm using for AddToCart:

```
const addToCart = (row) => {

        var exist = cartItems.find(currentItem => currentItem.PID === row.values.PID);

        if(exist !== undefined){
            console.log("Cart Item Already Exists");
        }
        else {
            const newCartItem = { ...row.values };
            setCartItems((cartItems) => [...cartItems, newCartItem]);
        }

    };
```

Below is the code showing where I'm utilizing the AddToCart function in the child component.
Every row in the table gets "Add To Cart" button appended as a column. So, when a specific row is clicked, that item's data gets passed to the AddToCart function so it can check for duplicates and add the information to the shopping cart.

```
const tableHooks = (hooks) => {
        hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
            {
                id: "Actions",
                Header: "Actions",
                Cell: ({ row }) => (
                    <button className="viewBtn" onClick={() => props.addToCart(row)}>
                        Add To Cart
                    </button>
                ),
                Filter: ColumnFilter
            },
            ...columns,
        ]);
    };
```

Below is the structure of an example row that's being passed to the parent components AddToCart function.

[image]

I've tried creating a temp array for cartItems before checking the list for a duplicate, and I've also tried using findIndex instead of find. But neither has helped. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in the `currentItem.PID === row.values.PID`. Are they of the same type? Maybe you're comparing `string` with `number`.

Fix: Use `==` (weak equality) instead of `===` (strict equality).

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not the issue. As I stated, I think it is because the array/list is empty during the function call itself. If I console.log the cartItems or try to iterate through them with a loop/forEach, I don't get anything as output. But I can still add items, so I know the rest of the function is working and the list contains items.